Is there a way to create a generic "GetTaskInfo" method in TwinCAT?
I tried creating an abstract function block that can be extended with certain FBs that need the task information, most of the time this is only task cycle time. I went ahead and created the function block :
FUNCTION_BLOCK ABSTRACT FB_HasTaskInfo
VAR
    _PlcTaskInfo    : PlcTaskSystemInfo;
END_VAR

Property TaskInfo
{attribute 'monitoring':='call'}
PROPERTY TaskInfo : REFERENCE TO PlcTaskSystemInfo

Get accesssor:
VAR
    taskIndex   : DINT;
END_VAR

IF _plcTaskInfo.CycleTime = 0 THEN
    taskIndex := Tc2_System.GETCURTASKINDEXEX();
    IF taskIndex <> 0 THEN
        _PlcTaskInfo := _TaskInfo[taskindex];
    END_IF
END_IF

TaskInfo REF= _PlcTaskInfo;

This works fine inside the library and the tests also pass. The problem comes when I import the library into another project, the property's get accessor is throwing an error that it basically can't find _taskInfo[taskIndex] which kind of makes sense since the data type is auto generated for each PLC project by TwinCAT I assume (it is located in external folder). I am guessing the _taskInfo is also auto generated, somehow?

The image show the error inside the imported library:

Is there a way to make the generic function, or do you need to explicitly always do the call from within the PLC project?

Instead of just asking for
_TaskInfo[taskindex]

prepend it with a namespace
TwinCAT_SystemInfoVarList._TaskInfo[taskindex]


I will try, I was trying for autocomplete to do it, but it didnt budge ( I have insert with namespace enabled)

It works, you are a legend sir, thank you :) Is it a "bug" that you can't go to definition or insert with namespace?

You can't go to definition, because all Beckhoff libraries are compiled libraries, therefore implementation details are hidden. Don't know about inserting with namespace, I don't use that feature

Ah, they explicitly say that you need to use the namespace.The corresponding namespace is'TwinCAT_SystemInfoVarList.' This must be specified for use in a library, for example.. Good to know https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/714821259.html&id=
